# Combining two SQL statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, where-clause

I would like to know if it is possible to combine two statements into a single one in SQLite.

The first statement is the following:

```
SELECT MAX(goodput_mbps), packetsize_bytes 
FROM data 
WHERE src = "A" AND dst = "B" 
GROUP BY packetsize_bytes
```

which produces somthing like:

```
(1.065251641628522, 32)
(2.023058064838313, 64)
(3.9937457226166333, 128)
(7.13931248161879, 256)
(9.732371794078158, 384)
(12.030082350641777, 512)
(14.941748420411137, 640)
(16.768300606617814, 768)
(19.55032187231529, 1028)
(21.54109687187735, 1280)
(23.025071751003825, 1460)
(15.871752691948677, 1534)
(17.309115863006014, 1788)
(18.40483524961694, 2048)
```

For each entry I then run another SQL query using as parameters for the WHERE clause the first and the second entry of each record, for example for the first entry of the previous result set I would run:

```
SELECT MAX(median)-MIN(median) / MAX(bitrate_mbps)-MIN(bitrate_mbps), packetsize_bytes 
FROM data 
WHERE src = "A" and dst = "B" and packetsize_bytes = 32 and bitrate_mbps < 1.12 
ORDER BY bitrate_mbps ASC
```

which produces something like:

```
(0.035000000000000225, 32)
```

Basically I would like to have a single query that produces something like:

```
(x, 32)
(x, 64)
(x, 128)
(x, 256)
(x, 384)
(x, 512)
(x, 640)
(x, 768)
(x, 1028)
(x, 1280)
(x, 1460)
(x, 1534)
(x, 1788)
(x, 2048)
```

Is this possible in SQLite? I know that there is the WHERE IN clause but it seem to accept a single parameter.

Comment: I've edited the question in order to clarify some points

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(median)-MIN(median) / MAX(bitrate_mbps)-MIN(bitrate_mbps), 
       packetsize_bytes 
FROM 
    (SELECT MAX(goodput_mbps) , packetsize_bytes 
    FROM data 
    WHERE src = "A" AND dst = "B" 
    GROUP BY packetsize_bytes) 

WHERE packetsize_bytes = 32 and bitrate_mbps < 1.12 
ORDER BY bitrate_mbps ASC
```

Comment: The inner query has no columns named `median` or `bitrate_mbps`.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify "combine", but if you simply want to have the results of both queries, you can combine them with [UNION ALL](http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT MAX(goodput_mbps), packetsize_bytes
FROM data
WHERE src = 'A' AND dst = 'B'
GROUP BY packetsize_bytes

UNION ALL

SELECT MAX(median)-MIN(median) / MAX(bitrate_mbps)-MIN(bitrate_mbps),
       packetsize_bytes
FROM data
WHERE src = 'A' AND dst = 'B'
  AND packetsize_bytes = 32 AND bitrate_mbps < 1.12

ORDER BY bitrate_mbps ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(d1.median)-MIN(d1.median) / MAX(d1.bitrate_mbps)-MIN(d1.bitrate_mbps), d2.packetsize_bytes 
FROM data d1, (SELECT MAX(goodput_mbps), packetsize_bytes FROM data WHERE src = "A" AND dst = "B" GROUP BY packetsize_bytes) d2  
WHERE d1.src = "A" and d1.dst = "B" and d1.packetsize_bytes = d2.packetsize_bytes and d1.bitrate_mbps < "d2.MAX(goodput_mbps)"  
GROUP BY d2.packetsize_bytes
ORDER BY d2.packetsize_bytes ASC
```

Answer (score -2):

No, you can't, since SQLite doesn't natively support analytical functions nor pl/sql.